# Booting to Busybox, Read only Filesystem and loads of Bad Blocks

Tags: hard-drive

So I had windows 10 on my laptop and then I installed Ubuntu over it.

At the moment I'm not sure if my drive is screwed or not, when I boot it goes to grub, if I select Ubuntu it goes to Busybox (without any instruction to run fsck) then if I restart the system and do the same it tells me to run fsck, after I do that I can type exit and I get into Ubuntu, but some of my programs like steam and firefox have weird inconsistent errors and I've tried doing some stuff other people suggested but my filesystem is in read only (write protected) mode so most of it doesn't work. I did

> sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda1

in the terminal and I got a ton of bad blocks, I accidentally stopped the process at block 72209031 but anyway this is how many I had so far:

> shafik@shafik-SATELLITE-C50-B:~$ sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda1
>   Checking blocks 0 to 484306943
>   Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): 2048504
>   2048505
>   2048506
>   2048507
>   2265236
>   2265237
>   2265238
>   2265239
>   2265240
>   2265241
>   2265242
>   2265243
>   2265244
>   2265245
>   2277304
>   2277305
>   2277306
>   2277307
>   2286732
>   2286733
>   2286734
>   2286735
>   2286740
>   2286741
>   2286742
>   2286743
>   2289656
>   2289657
>   2289658
>   2289659
>   2289660
>   2289661
>   2289662
>   2289663
>   2290956
>   2290957
>   2290958
>   2290959
>   2290964
>   2290965
>   2290966
>   2290967
>   2290972
>   2290973
>   2290974
>   2290975
>   2290976
>   2290977
>   2290978
>   2290979
>   2292244
>   2292245
>   2292246
>   2292247
>   2292280
>   2292281
>   2292282
>   2292283
>   2293568
>   2293569
>   2293570
>   2293571
>   2293600
>   2293601
>   2293602
>   2293603
>   2294888
>   2294889
>   2294890
>   2294891
>   71159840
>   71159841
>   71159842
>   71159843
>   71159844
>   71159845
>   71159846
>   71159847
>   71159848
>   71159849
>   71159850
>   71159851
>   71159852
>   71159853
>   71159854
>   71159855
>   71159856
>   71159857
>   71159858
>   71159859
>   71159860
>   71159861
>   71159862
>   71159863
>   71159864
>   71159865
>   71159866
>   71159867
>   71159868
>   71159869
>   71159870
>   71159871
>   71159896
>   71159897
>   71159898
>   71159899
>   71159912
>   71159913
>   71159914
>   71159915
>   71159916
>   71159917
>   71159918
>   71159919
>   71159964
>   71159965
>   71159966
>   71159967
>   71159968
>   71159969
>   71159970
>   71159971
>   71159972
>   71159973
>   71159974
>   71159975
>   71159984
>   71159985
>   71159986
>   71159987
>   71159988
>   71159989
>   71159990
>   71159991
>   71159992
>   71159993
>   71159994
>   71159995
>   71159996
>   71159997
>   71159998
>   71159999
>   71160028
>   71160029
>   71160030
>   71160031
>   71160032
>   71160033
>   71160034
>   71160035
>   71160036
>   71160037
>   71160038
>   71160039
>   71160060
>   71160061
>   71160062
>   71160063
>   71160072
>   71160073
>   71160074
>   71160075
>   71160080
>   71160081
>   71160082
>   71160083
>   71160084
>   71160085
>   71160086
>   71160087
>   71551280
>   71551281
>   71551300
>   71551301
>   71551302
>   71553056
>   71553057
>   71553058
>   71553059
>   71553060
>   71553061
>   71553062
>   71553063
>   71553104
>   71553105
>   71553106
>   71553107
>   71553116
>   71553117
>   71553118
>   71553119
>   71553120
>   71553121
>   71553122
>   71553123
>   71553124
>   71553125
>   71553126
>   71553127
>   71553164
>   71553165
>   71553166
>   71553167
>   71553180
>   71553181
>   71553182
>   71553183
>   71553208
>   71553209
>   71553210
>   71553211
>   71553220
>   71553221
>   71553222
>   71553223
>   71553224
>   71553225
>   71553226
>   71553227
>   71553240
>   71553241
>   71553242
>   71553243
>   71553244
>   71553245
>   71553246
>   71553247
>   71553248
>   71553249
>   71553250
>   71553251
>   71553252
>   71553253
>   71553254
>   71553255
>   71553268
>   71553269
>   71553270
>   71553271
>   71553284
>   71553285
>   71553286
>   71553287
>   71553288
>   71553289
>   71553290
>   71553291
>   71553292
>   71553293
>   71553294
>   71553295
>   71553308
>   71553309
>   71553310
>   71553311
>   71553312
>   71553313
>   71553314
>   71553315
>   71553316
>   71553317
>   71553318
>   71553319
>   71553332
>   71553333
>   71553334
>   71553335
>   71553356
>   71553357
>   71553358
>   71553359
>   71553360
>   71553361
>   71553362
>   71553363
>   71553364
>   71553365
>   71553366
>   71553367
>   71553388
>   71553389
>   71553390
>   71553391
>   71553436
>   71553437
>   71553438
>   71553439
>   71553440
>   71553441
>   71553442
>   71553443
>   71553452
>   71553453
>   71553454
>   71553455
>   71553464
>   71553465
>   71553466
>   71553467
>   71553468
>   71553469
>   71553470
>   71553471
>   71553472
>   71553473
>   71553474
>   71553475
>   71553476
>   71553477
>   71553478
>   71553479
>   71553480
>   71553481
>   71553482
>   71553483
>   71553484
>   71553485
>   71553486
>   71553487
>   71553488
>   71553489
>   71553490
>   71553491
>   71553500
>   71553501
>   71553502
>   71553503
>   71553516
>   71553517
>   71553518
>   71553519
>   71553524
>   71553525
>   71553526
>   71553527
>   71553592
>   71553593
>   71553594
>   71553595
>   71553596
>   71553597
>   71553598
>   71553599
>   71553612
>   71553613
>   71553614
>   71553615
>   71553616
>   71553617
>   71553618
>   71553619
>   71553632
>   71553633
>   71553634
>   71553635
>   71553636
>   71553637
>   71553638
>   71553639
>   71553652
>   71553653
>   71553654
>   71553655
>   71553656
>   71553657
>   71553658
>   71553659
>   71553660
>   71553661
>   71553662
>   71553663
>   71553692
>   71553693
>   71553694
>   71553695
>   71553704
>   71553705
>   71553706
>   71553707
>   71946440
>   71946441
>   71946442
>   71946444
>   71946445
>   71946446
>   71946447
>   71946448
>   71946449
>   71946450
>   71946451
>   71946452
>   71946453
>   71946454
>   71946455
>   71946456
>   71946457
>   71946458
>   71946459
>   71946460
>   71946461
>   71946462
>   71946463
>   71946464
>   71946465
>   71946466
>   71946467
>   71946468
>   71946469
>   71946470
>   71946471
>   71946556
>   71946557
>   71946558
>   71946559
>   71946560
>   71946561
>   71946562
>   71946563
>   71946564
>   71946565
>   71946566
>   71946567
>   71946568
>   71946569
>   71946570
>   71946571
>   71946572
>   71946573
>   71946574
>   71946575
>   71946576
>   71946577
>   71946578
>   71946579
>   71946580
>   71946581
>   71946582
>   71946583
>   71946584
>   71946585
>   71946586
>   71946587
>   71946588
>   71946589
>   71946590
>   71946591
>   71946592
>   71946593
>   71946594
>   71946595
>   71946596
>   71946597
>   71946598
>   71946599
>   71946916
>   71946917
>   71946918
>   71946919
>   71946920
>   71946921
>   71946922
>   71946923
>   71946932
>   71946933
>   71946934
>   71946935
>   71946936
>   71946937
>   71946938
>   71946939
>   71946940
>   71946941
>   71946942
>   71946943
>   71946976
>   71946977
>   71946980
>   71946981
>   71946982
>   71946983
>   71946984
>   71946985
>   71946986
>   71946987
>   72207240
>   72207241
>   72207242
>   72207243
>   72207284
>   72207285
>   72207286
>   72207287
>   72207356
>   72207357
>   72207358
>   72207359
>   72207776
>   72207777
>   72207778
>   72207779
>   72207780
>   72207781
>   72207782
>   72207783
>   72208936
>   72208937
>   72208938
>   72208939
>   72208940
>   72208941
>   72208942
>   72208943
>   72208944
>   72208945
>   72208946
>   72208947
>   72209024
>   72209025
>   72209026
>   72209027
>   72209028
>   72209029
>   72209030
>   72208937
>   72208938
>   72208939
>   72208940
>   72208941
>   72208942
>   72208943
>   72208944
>   72208945
>   72208946
>   72208947
>   72209024
>   72209025
>   72209026
>   72209027
>   72209028
>   72209029
>   72209030

Long story short I have a lot of bad blocks, I did

> sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda

to try and get as much info on the hard drive as I could for you guys, the output was:

shafik@shafik-SATELLITE-C50-B:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
[sudo] password for shafik: 
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-72-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABF...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050
Serial Number:    94B7C7ZLT
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 5c3603549
Firmware Version: AM0P3M
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Apr 13 11:30:30 2017 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   0) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   099   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1205
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       837
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       5432
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       1153
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   115   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       776
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       656
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       469
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2563
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       31 (Min/Max 9/50)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       341
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       240
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       1079
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       267
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 65535 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 65535 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1135 hours (47 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH

---

40 51 08 d0 10 46 e0  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x004610d0 = 4591824

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name

---

25 00 08 d0 10 46 e0 00      00:01:01.175  READ DMA EXT
  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0c      00:01:01.173  [VENDOR SPECIFIC]
  25 00 08 d0 10 46 e0 00      00:00:57.397  READ DMA EXT
  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0c      00:00:57.395  [VENDOR SPECIFIC]
  25 00 08 d0 10 46 e0 00      00:00:53.619  READ DMA EXT

Error 65534 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1135 hours (47 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH

---

40 51 08 d0 10 46 e0  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x004610d0 = 4591824

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name

---

25 00 08 d0 10 46 e0 00      00:00:57.397  READ DMA EXT
  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0c      00:00:57.395  [VENDOR SPECIFIC]
  25 00 08 d0 10 46 e0 00      00:00:53.619  READ DMA EXT
  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0c      00:00:53.617  [VENDOR SPECIFIC]
  25 00 36 ca 10 46 e0 00      00:00:49.829  READ DMA EXT

Error 65533 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1135 hours (47 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH

---

40 51 08 d0 10 46 e0  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x004610d0 = 4591824

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name

---

25 00 08 d0 10 46 e0 00      00:00:53.619  READ DMA EXT
  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0c      00:00:53.617  [VENDOR SPECIFIC]
  25 00 36 ca 10 46 e0 00      00:00:49.829  READ DMA EXT
  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0c      00:00:49.828  [VENDOR SPECIFIC]
  25 00 36 ca 10 46 e0 00      00:00:46.040  READ DMA EXT

Error 65532 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1135 hours (47 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH

---

40 51 30 d0 10 46 e0  Error: UNC 48 sectors at LBA = 0x004610d0 = 4591824

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name

---

25 00 36 ca 10 46 e0 00      00:00:49.829  READ DMA EXT
  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0c      00:00:49.828  [VENDOR SPECIFIC]
  25 00 36 ca 10 46 e0 00      00:00:46.040  READ DMA EXT
  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0c      00:00:46.039  [VENDOR SPECIFIC]
  25 00 36 ca 10 46 e0 00      00:00:42.264  READ DMA EXT

Error 65531 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1135 hours (47 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH

---

40 51 30 d0 10 46 e0  Error: UNC 48 sectors at LBA = 0x004610d0 = 4591824

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name

---

25 00 36 ca 10 46 e0 00      00:00:46.040  READ DMA EXT
  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0c      00:00:46.039  [VENDOR SPECIFIC]
  25 00 36 ca 10 46 e0 00      00:00:42.264  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 0a c0 10 46 e0 00      00:00:42.264  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 06 ca 10 46 e0 00      00:00:42.263  READ DMA EXT

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

I'm just wondering if my hdd is totally screwed or is there a bunch of commands I can run to fix it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Totally screwed.

Answer (score 0):

You have numerous SMART errors which indicate that your drive is indeed dying. The blocks of SMART output that look like this..

```
Error 65531 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1135 hours (47 days + 7 hours) When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.
```

..suggest that these errors were encountered fairly early on in your drives life. 47 days is not old for a drive; it's well within the RMA period and points at a potentially faulty drive out of the box. It looks like bad blocks or bad sectors is causing the kernel to drop you to a BusyBox shell, or not boot consistently. If you have any read capability on the drive at all, I would get all important data off of it and look at a replacement. When a drive starts dying (and yours has!) there is very little that can be done about it.